# Can I keep my WatchKit App running in the background on the Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, background, watchkit

I want to know if there is anyway to keep my WatchKit app running in the background, or if I can possibly program it to launch (i.e. transfer from inactive state to active state) once a certain condition is fulfilled?

My app is running perfectly while the WK App is open and active, and it even runs fine when the iPhone is asleep, or when the parent iOS app is in BG mode.  However, I really need my app to continue running in the background on the watch itself.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible. Because Apple Document for `watchkit` clearly mentions that "*WatchKit extensions do not support background execution modes,they run only while the user is interacting with the corresponding app on Apple Watch.*".

You can refer apple document [Link to Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html)

Read **Communicating Directly with Your Containing iOS App**.

Comment: So why does it work on the simulator? I have an NSTimer that runs on the Apple watch simulator in background with no problem. Not on device itself though

Comment: yea it works for me in the simulator too..??but not on device